# regular expression matching support for '.' and '*'

Tags: algorithm, recursion, string-matching

[Implement regular expression matching with support for ‘.’ and ‘*’.](http://www.leetcode.com/2011/09/regular-expression-matching.html)

‘.’ Matches any single character. ‘*’ Matches zero or more of the preceding element. The matching should cover the entire input string (not partial).

> Some examples:
>
> isMatch(“aa”,”a”) → false
>
> isMatch(“aa”,”aa”) → true
>
> isMatch(“aaa”,”aa”) → false
>
> isMatch(“aa”, “a*”) → true
>
> isMatch(“aa”, “.*”) → true
>
> isMatch(“ab”, “.*”) → true
>
> isMatch(“aab”, “c*a*b”) → true

The author gives the following solution, which is really beautiful.

```
bool isMatch(const char *s, const char *p) {
  assert(s && p);
  if (*p == '\0') return *s == '\0';

  // next char is not '*': must match current character
  if (*(p+1) != '*') {
    assert(*p != '*');
    return ((*p == *s) || (*p == '.' && *s != '\0')) && isMatch(s+1, p+1);
  }
  // next char is '*'
  while ((*p == *s) || (*p == '.' && *s != '\0')) {
    if (isMatch(s, p+2)) return true;
    s++;
  }
  return isMatch(s, p+2);
}
```

The author also gives some further thoughts:

If you think carefully, you can exploit some cases that the above code runs in exponential complexity.

> Could you think of some examples?  How would you make the above code
>   more efficient?
>
> I came up one case that takes a long time to get the result while the
>   length of string s and p are not huge.
>
> s[] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
>   p[] ="a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*a*b"

Can anyone help me verify this answer?
How to think this kind of finding extreme testing questions?

Comment: Hint: put some "logging" in the `isMatch` function to announce its progress.  From there you should be able to devise a general formula that will tell you how many "steps" it will require for your example.  Ultimately, this is a math (counting) problem. :)

Comment: @RayToal, yes, I have already done the similar experiment. I define a global parameter named <code>count<code>. And then adding by one in the <code>isMatch<code> function. Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Yes, but you may also want to see how far along you are rather than just counting.  Logging things like the current index into the string and the depth of the recursion will give you interesting insight into the workings of the algorithm.

Comment: @RayToal, thanks very much for your kind help. I still cannot figure out how to use the "logging" skill and at the same time I really want to master it so that I can handle all of these kind of cases in future. Can you give me more hints? I'm not asking you to help me write the code. Or is there any example about "logging" skill? Really appreciate your help

Comment: Oh, by logging I only mean something like regular old `printf`. I will submit an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best why to understand why your case exhibits exponential behavior is to first experiment with the code a bit and then try to glean from it some empirical data and make hypotheses.

First, let's add some simple "logging":

```
#include <cassert> 
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int count = 0;

bool isMatch(const char *s, const char *p) {
    printf("%5d   %s   %s\n", count++, s, p);  
    .
    .
    .
```

Now let's run a number of experiments, making sure to reset the count before each experiment (remember in real code global variables are to be avoided :) )

```
isMatch("a", "a*b");
isMatch("aa", "a*a*b");
isMatch("aaa", "a*a*a*b");
isMatch("aaaa", "a*a*a*a*b");
isMatch("aaaaa", "a*a*a*a*a*b");
isMatch("aaaaaa", "a*a*a*a*a*a*b");
```

You can look at the outputs of each, and look at the number of lines generated for each and ask yourself "how does the number of recursive calls grow as I lengthen my string?"  (Classic empirical algorithm analysis!)

I've done the `aaa` case for you here: http://ideone.com/8t2kS

You can see it took 34 steps.  Look at the output; it should give you some insight into the nature of the matching.  And do try for strings of increasing length.  Happy experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case where implementing regular expression matching via recursive descent leads to pathological behaviour.

The right way to implement this is to turn your regex into a nondeterministic state machine.  It takes (quite a bit) more code, but will run in linear time for any given regex.

Here's a [first class article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) on the subject.

Cheers!